# How to get $form_state->getUserInput() ( i.e, what the user entered in the input ) in each inline entity form and not only in the first one?

Tags: entities, forms, 9

I use the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module to build nested multiple forms.
I have a **design** form in which there is an inline form - **garment**. And inside the garment form, there is a product field.

In the `hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()` I get `$field_product_user_input`

```
$field_product_user_input = $form_state->getUserInput()['field_design']['form']['inline_entity_form']['entities']['0']['form']['field_garment']['form']['inline_entity_form']['entities']['0']['form']['field_product']['0']['target_id'];
```

And I get what I need. But when I add a second inline entity form in the design, it gets the first garment's field value. This occurs because the second form has a key of **'1**' in the 'entities' array, while the code above uses **'0'** for the first form.

`$form_state->getUserInput()` show this result:

```
result = [
  'field_design' => [
    'form' => [
      'inline_entity_form' => [
        'entities' => [
          '0' => [
            'form' => [
              'field_garment' => [
                'form' => [
                  'inline_entity_form' => [
                    'entities' => [
                      '0' => [...],
                      '1' => [...] // new garment
                    ],
                  ],
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `$form_state->getUserInput()['_triggering_element_name']`
2. Using such PHP functions as: `strpos()`, `str_replace()` and `explode()` build an array of parents from what is in `$form_state->getUserInput()['_triggering_element_name']`
3. Use `NestedArray::getValue()`

Example:

```
if ($triggering_element_name = $form_state->getUserInput()['_triggering_element_name']) {
  if (strpos($triggering_element_name, '[field_product][0][target_id]') !== FALSE) {
    $triggering_element_name = str_replace(']', '', $triggering_element_name);
    $parents = explode('[', $triggering_element_name);
    if ($field_product = NestedArray::getValue($form_state->getUserInput(), $parents)) {
      $entity_product_id = EntityAutocomplete::extractEntityIdFromAutocompleteInput($field_product);
    }
  }
}
```